# How does bootstrap4's class="card-img" scale images for smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website trying to make images scale nicely for mobile device and have found that using 
`img class="card-img"`
makes the image width change as the devices width is changing, however if this class is set it runins different part of my layout.
Is there a way to uses `img class="rounded"` and achive the same image scaling?

Please bare in mind that I am quite new to CSS so I have very limited knowledge and have so far been unable to find an answer to this else where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it depends on you what you want.
There are different classes in bootstrap for images.
Normally for images scale nicely "img-fluid" class used.
For more information please refer this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/